# C# debug on the exe called from other project in the same Solution

Tags: c#, camera, processstartinfo

I have the problem with camera"build In" I want to  debug to investigate more in the issue but I face a problem which is my class call  the .exe project directly it doesn't use no interface or something else so this prevent me to debug.
The ".exe" exist in my solution they use ProcessStartInfo to started.
Can somebody give me a way how i can debug into the exe from the other project in the same solution 
thinks for you help ine advance

Comment: So as I understand it your project `Process.Start()`s a `.exe` file and you want to debug the execution of that? Is that a native `.exe` or is it a .NET assembly? Do you have source code for it? You can't really look into that `exe` nicely with your visual studio debugging tools, but any other debugger (`x64dbg`, `OllyDbg`) is helpfull. What exactly is the problem with the .exe? If it doesn't behave like it should (bug inside that program), reverse-engineering the problem might be hard. It might be better to ask the creators of that program for help.

Comment: It sound like he has the code within the solution - but calls a compiled version using Process.Start() on the exe.  In Visual Studio you can attach the debugger to an exe by name and then it will hit break points/allow you to debug etc

Comment: yes i have the exe in the solution but I don't know how I can attach the debugger to the exe, I already try to add breakpoint on the code but it doesn't work, I never reach breakpoint .

Comment: I resolve the problem by calling  directly the Main  Program instead of using the ProcessStartInfo that launch the EXE   and it works  fine